# drawing lines that have the same latitude and longitude on a map (ggplot, geom_curve)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to get some help from you regarding drawing lines on map using ggplot in R.

Suppose there are two observations, A and B, and their origin and destination longitude and latitude are the same with each other.
I'd like to draw two lines that are not overlapped on the map.

I tried with geom_curve() but it seems to draw two lines on the same trajectory.

Is there a smart way to resolve this issue?
I would say this is sort of similar to geom_repel() but not for texts or labels but for curves.

Thanks.

Comment: Hopefully my answer also gives you an idea of how to mock up some sample data for next time as this question may get closed fairly quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a base R solution (a `tidyverse` one wld look a bit less "code-y" but do essentially the same thing.

If these are, indeed, X & Y pairs then all you have to do is add a mid-point and jitter said mid-point. I have not fully "solutioned" this for you since you really do need to do some work (like filtering the data frame for only those lines with same start/end points before doing this jitter hack):

```
library(ggplot2)

lines_df <- as.data.frame(state.center, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[c(4,20,4,20),]
lines_df$grp <- c("a", "a", "b", "b")
lines_df$where <- rep("end", 4)

do.call(
  rbind.data.frame,
  lapply(
    split(lines_df, lines_df$grp),
    function(.df) {
      rbind.data.frame(
        .df, 
        data.frame(
          x = sum(.df$x)/2, y = sum(.df$y)/2, 
          grp = .df$grp[1], where = "mid",
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE
        )
      )

    }
  ) 
) -> lines_df

lines_df[lines_df$where == "mid", "y"] <- jitter(lines_df[lines_df$where == "mid", "y"])

ggplot(lines_df, aes(x, y, group=grp)) +
  geom_line(aes(color=grp))
```

[image]

NOTE: this does not take into account the reality of the earth being curved and naive division by 2 over a sufficiently long line (esp depending on the projection) is less than ideal, but this gives you one way to attack the problem.

`tidyverse` 4eva  folks who also think this is the most straightforward approach are encouraged to post a `tidyverse` solution with the same logic.

Comment: Thank you @hrbrmstr. This is extremely helpful.